# Files not uploaded in Django form - encoding type incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

We use Django with Crispy forms in our websites. I have a form rendered by `{% crispy form %}`. Here is the code of the form:

```
class ProfileForm(AddAttributesToFieldsMixin, CleanDateOfBirthMixin, LocalizedFirstLastNameMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    profile_picture = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=CustomPhotoWidget, label=_('Update your profile picture'), error_messages={'required': _("A profile picture is required.")})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('slug', 'gender', 'date_of_birth', 'profile_picture')
```

The form uses `CustomPhotoWidget` which is defined like this:

```
class CustomPhotoWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        return render_to_string(template_name='accounts/edit_profile/widgets/photo_widget.html', context={
            'name': name,
            'user_photo': self.attrs['user'].photo,
        })
```

But the problem is, when I upload a file from my browser, I receive an error message "No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form." and the file is not saved. The encoding type of the form is incorrect. How do I change the encoding type with Crispy forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/issues/22) on GitHub and asked for help from a developer I work with, [Aaron Chong](https://github.com/acjh). He checked and found out the problem. `CustomPhotoWidget` should be defined like this:

```
class CustomPhotoWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    needs_multipart_form = True

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        return render_to_string(template_name='accounts/edit_profile/widgets/photo_widget.html', context={
            'name': name,
            'user_photo': self.attrs['user'].photo,
        })
```

`needs_multipart_form = True` is what was needed to fix the encoding type of the form. I'm uploading this solution to Stack Overflow because I didn't find `needs_multipart_form` documented in other questions on the website.